# Why is My Listview is not showing my items?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview that I want to show several items. However, after the program compiles, nothing shows up and I am unsure as to why.

```
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.quikList);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Hello");
    list.add("Is it me youre looking for?");
    list.add("I can see it in your smile and I want so badly to make this listview work");

    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, list);
listview.setAdapter(aa);
```

I don't know why this pretty basic task is not working. I think it might be due to android.R.id.text1, but I'm not sure as to why. Any sort of light anyone can shed on this topic would be fantastic.

Comment: An update: The list for sure has the items stored in it. I checked with logcat

Comment: Why not use a recyclerview?

Comment: Try to use the constructor with 3 parameters, without the TextViewResId : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20T[])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of 3rd param just remove this line `android.R.id.text1`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listView.setAdapter(aa);
```

**Solution 2:**

May be your theme issues which means your `Textview` color same as `Listview` background color..

so just change your **listview** background color...

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
```

Comment: Haha it was Solution 2... I hate myself

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
ListView listView = (Listview)findViewById(R.id.quikList);

String list[] = {"Hello","Is it me youre looking for?","I can see it in your smile and I want so badly to make this listview work"};   

ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView, list);

listview.setAdapter(aa);
```